# Mysql TRIGGER ON UPDATE with Functions

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, match

im trying to make an trigger that updates a table when i modify another table...
Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updpartido AFTER UPDATE ON partidos
ON EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @vgls = SELECT vgoles(NEW.eqvis)
        SET @lgls = SELECT vgoles(NEW.eqloc)
        UPDATE equipos SET gf=@vgls WHERE id=NEW.eqvis
        UPDATE equipos SET gf=@lgls WHERE id=NEW.eqloc
    END
```

What it must do is, when i update an match, it must automaticly run this trigger and update the goals.

But it gives me an error.
What im doing wrong? Thanks and have a nice day...!

Comment: @muistooshort 
   [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   DECLARE at vgls int;
   DECLARE at lgls int;
   SET at vgls' at line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that you don't have any statement terminators in your trigger, that will generate some complaints because, for example, `SET @lgls = SELECT vgoles(NEW.eqloc) UPDATE equipos SET gf=@vgls WHERE id=NEW.eqvis` doesn't make any sense. So you need some semicolons in the trigger but you also need to get those semicolons past the parser by temporarily changing the delimiter. You're also using `ON EACH ROW` when it should be `FOR EACH ROW`:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER updpartido AFTER UPDATE ON partidos
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @vgls = SELECT vgoles(NEW.eqvis);
        SET @lgls = SELECT vgoles(NEW.eqloc);
        UPDATE equipos SET gf=@vgls WHERE id=NEW.eqvis;
        UPDATE equipos SET gf=@lgls WHERE id=NEW.eqloc;
    END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i forgot about the delimiters!
It worked like a charm! Thanks so much @muistooshort !
Have a nice day!